# Where should I insert or inject interceptor

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

This is something I have written in my service, Can anyone tell me where and how am I supposed to insert the http interceptor, so that I can check out each response and see if the status code contains '25001' and if yes then redirect it to the login page, please help.

```
'use strict';
homeApp.factory('AdminDashboardService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){       
        return {
             'response': function(response) {
              console.log("Yes Command comes here");
              return response;
            },

            getAllHolidays: function(monthYearArrayForHolidayList) {
                console.log("For full list of holidays list length: "+monthYearArrayForHolidayList.length);
                var isMonthly="no";
                return $http.get('/tasktrac/holiday/getHoliday/isMonthly/'+isMonthly+'/'+monthYearArrayForHolidayList)
                        .then(
                                function(response){
                                    return response.data;
                                }, 
                                function(errResponse){
                                    //console.error('Error while fetching holiday');
                                    return $q.reject(errResponse);
                                }
                        );
        }}]);

homeApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AdminDashboardService');
}]);
```

Master app.js

```
'use strict';
var App = angular.module('myApp',[],['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap','UserValidation']);

var homeApp = angular.module("homeApp",['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

var cApp = angular.module('clientApp',['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

Comment: I can provide more information, but please help me get rid of this problem. I have done this in jQuery but unable to implement it in angular

Answer (score 0):

Interceptors should be defined in separatet modules. Usually this is done in a `factory`, as you've already done. An Interceptor gets executed every time before a request or after a response (regarding on your configuration). In your case it should get executed after your response.

```
homeApp.factory('AdminDashboardService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    'response': function(response) {
      // do something on success
      return response;
    },
  }
}]);
```

To get your interceptor fire on each response you will now have to add it into your `$httpProvider`.

```
module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AdminDashboardService');
}]);
```

By doing so, your Interceptor will now fire after each response. You can take a deeper look on how Interceptors are working in Angular at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) or [here](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/), for some examples.

Comment: Hey Aer0, Now it is saying that, "ReferenceError: module is not defined" :(

Comment: `module` can be seen as a placeholder. It's just as you've done before with your `homeApp`. You need to call `.config()` on your main Angular file. I would really recommend you to take a look into the examples, that may hepl a lot and also answer upcoming questions.

Comment: I have updated in the question the master file in which all the 'app' are defined, You said in your earlier post that I need to call .config() on main Angular, did you mean this file as main file

Comment: In your case it would be `App.config(...)`

Comment: Can you see, I have added "homeApp.config(...)" but it throws me the following error. "Error: [$injector:cdep] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/cdep?p0=%24http%20%3C-%20AdminDashboardService%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24compile"